# sqlserver running count

Tags: sql-server

Imagine the below table as A

```
col1 col2 col3 rank
 1     2   n    5
 1     2   n    6
 2     3   a    3
```

While inserting below records from table B to table A, the rank column valus should be keep incrementing if the same records inserts.

Records in table B which gonna insert into A are

```
col1 col2 col3
 1     2    n
 2     3    a
```

The desired output in table A after the above records are inserted is,

```
 col1 col2 col3 rank
   1    2   n    5
   1    2   n    6
   1    2   n    7
   2    3   a    3
   2    3   a    4
```

Please help me how to acheive this.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the record in B are unique, then you could use a query like this

--------------**EDIT**-------------------

If B can have multiple records, you can use row_number() funcion with partition

```
insert into TestA
select b.*, 
(select max([rank]) from TestA where col1 = b.col1 and col2 = b.col2 and col3 = b.col3) 
+ row_number()over (partition by col1, col2, col3 order by col1, col2,col3 asc) as N
 from TestB b
```

--------------**END EDIT**-------------------

Note: i renamed the table: TestA and TestB

```
insert into TestA
select b.*, (select max([rank])+1 from TestAwhere col1 = b.col1 and col2 = b.col2 and col3 = b.col3)
 from TestB b
```

or with a JOIN like this

```
insert into testa
select b.*, mr+1 from TestB b
join
(select col1, col2, col3, max([rank]) as mr
from TestA A
group by col1, col2, col3) as M
on 
b.col1 = M.col1 and b.col2 = M.col2 and b.col3 =M.col3
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for ur help. The first code cant work since ran column is not there in table b. I tried the 2nd one. The problem with this is, if the table B has duplicate row as same as first row, then it is insering the same rank to the second entry also. It has to be incremented.

Comment: I modified the query to work with the multiple entry in table B

Answer (score 2):

I would use an [`INSTEAD OF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089.aspx) `INSERT` [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) for this. Like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER rankInsertTrigger
ON A
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO A(col1, col2, col3, rank)
    SELECT i.col1, i.col2, i.col3,
           MAX(SELECT a.rank
               FROM A AS a
               WHERE a.col1 = i.col1
                 AND a.col2 = i.col2
                 AND a.col3 = i.col3) + 1
    FROM inserted i
END
```

Every time you now insert values into table `A`, this trigger runs and replaces the original insert with an insert that sets the `rank` you want.

For example, when you do `INSERT INTO A(col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1, 2, n)`, what actually runs is the insert statement in the trigger (which takes the original values for `col1`, `col2`, `col3` but overwrites `rank`).

Comment: could you please explain what that select clause in the trigger about to retrieve? It will be helpful for me to modify. Thanks for ur help.

Comment: Doesn't look like this will handle concurrent inserts.

Comment: @Robin Inside an INSERT trigger there is a table called `inserted` that represents the inserted record(s). The select statement selects data from the `inserted` table and determines the next `rank` and uses this data to insert in table `A`.

Comment: @Martin Correct, when concurrent inserts happen, you'll likely end up with duplicate `rank` values. The only fix is making sure no concurrent inserts take place or by having each individual insert run inside a serializable transaction (since you need a read lock on the rows that are selected in the `MAX` query). Not sure if a trigger is the best place to include such logic.